# Authentication failure

Tags: authentication, su

I'm using ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic.
I know root password and login before (my friend can use su command), root password not change but when i using **su command** it appear " **authentication failure**", What can i do ?

*I can't use sudo too, message " xxx is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."*
*Thanks. i already use my friend accout to login root and "sudo adduser  sudo".*

Comment: Do you mean you forgot your password? Adding more details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if your friend is using the same computer as you get him to add you to the sudo group by

```
    sudo adduser <yourusername> sudo
```